# Very basic Beginner Join Query for 3 tables

Tags: mysql, join

I have 3 tables, 'film', 'actor' and 'cast'. I want to get a list of actors that are in a certain film, but I am brand new to SQL and cannot figure out how to join the tables.

I am comfortable with the SELECT and WHERE, just not the FROM.

- **Film** has the following fields: `id`, `title` and `year`.
- **Actor** has the fields `id` and `name`.
- **Cast** has the fields `filmid` and `actorid`

Comment: I had assumed it was a site for  people who might be able to help me as I am a beginner.

Comment: But it **is not a tutorial site**

Comment: Please add the query you tried to your question.

Comment: OP probably means he is not familiar with JOINS.

Comment: I did assume I might get a response like this. I have been trying to find an answer through sql quizzes all day but I just needed a clear answer which would take someone about 10 seconds. Thanks for the help

Comment: Google `sql join tutorial` and get **889,000** options

Comment: SELECT actorid FROM (??) WHERE filmid= '11789'. Really simple I know but I am trying to teach myself and I needed some clarification about the FROM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join the tables like this

```
select a.name
from actor a
join cast c on a.id = c.actorid
join film f on f.id = c.filmid
where f.title = 'your movie title'
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for the help Juergden D. I have only been learning for a few weeks so this is really useful.

Comment: @ttttttttttttt - You may want to go through [SQL Zoo](http://sqlzoo.net/) tutorials from easy to a bit more  advanced queries.  It will take more than a day, but it's worth it.  I believe I first came to SO in search for help with one of the queries from that site.